# How to use Kubernetes endpoint object?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a mongodb server hosted outside GCP, I want to connect to it using Kubernetes endpoint service as shown here [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvpq4jqtuZ8]. How can I do that? Can you write a sample YAML file for the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use **static Kubernetes service**, when you have got **the Internal IP and Port number** for externally hosted service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: mongo
Spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 27017
   targetPort: 27017
```

As  there are no Pod selectors for this service , There will not be any endpoints thus we can create a endpoint object manually.

```
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: mongo
subsets:
- addresses:
    - ip: 10.240.0.4  # Replace ME with your IP
  ports:
    - port: 27017
```

make sure that service and endpoints are having same name (for example mongo)

> If the IP address changes in the future, you can update the Endpoint with the new IP address, and your applications won’t need to make any changes.[mapping-external-services](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services)

Comment: Thanks Suresh. Can I also know how to access this in Node & express js app?

Comment: How should I pass my url, username & password for the connection? Is it through service object? Can you please update the YAML accordingly?

Comment: you just need to give the name of the service which is mongo

Comment: for username and password, you can use secret object

Comment: If you click on the link, it provide more details, `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@mongo:<port>`